# Avoid 0 value in form

Tags: html, forms

I have a form, one of the field is so far a text value. I want to avoid the value 0 but still allow to type fraction such as 1/3. my fraction are then recalculated and rounded to the 4th digit.

I therefore can not use `<input type="number" min="0.0001">`

How can I do that?

Comment: You'll have to use jquery "keypress" method. or use an open source plugin out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Avoid 0 value in `<input>`, Allow typing of fractions such as 1/3, Recalculate and round value to 4th decimal.

---

**JavaScript:**

```
function calculateFraction(form){

    function returnError(){
        alert("You must enter a 'non-zero' numeric value")
        input.style.background = '#FDD'
        return false
    }

    //  Define input element to check
        var input = form["fraction"]    //  Input MUST be type="text"

    //  Breakpoint - if value can't be evaluated.
        if( !/^[0-9\/*\.\+-]*$/.test(input.value) )
            return returnError();

    //  Evaluate statement. i.e. compute fractions, etc.
        var value = eval(input.value)

    //  Test for '0'
        if( Number(value)==0 ){
            //  Failed Test - Do Something
            returnError()

            return false
        }

    //  Round to fourth decimal, define as the new input value
        input.value =   Math.round(value*10000)/10000

    //  Submit Form
        return true

}//endfunction
```

**HTML**

```
<form onsubmit="return calculateFraction(this);">
    <input type="text" name="fraction" />
    <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

**Caveats**

The `<input>` *MUST* be of `type="text"`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a JavaScript validation for the form? It allows you to be much more precise with what kind of data you accept.

Example JavaScript:

```
function validateNonzeroForm() {
    var a = document.forms["myForm"]["nonzero_number"].value;
    if (a == "0") {
        alert("Nonzero field cannot be zero. Please enter a number.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="demoForm" action="" onsubmit="return validateNonzeroForm()" method="post">
    Please write numbers: <input type="number" name="nonzero_number">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Cross-Browser '**Pattern**' Support

Validates all `<form>` `<input>` elements against your desired `.value` requirement using `pattern` attribute.

**JavaScript:**

```
function validateInputs(form){

    var all_valid = true
    for(var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++ ){
        var input = form.elements[i]

    //  Breakpoints:
        //  If we are not looking at an <input> element
        //  If the element does not have a pattern attribute
        if( input.tagName.toLowerCase().indexOf('input') == -1 ) continue;
        if( !input.getAttribute('pattern') ) continue;

    //  input Regex Pattern to test
        var pattern = new RegExp(input.getAttribute('pattern'),'g');

        if( pattern.test(input.value) ){
        //  Passed Test - Do Something
            input.style.background = 'transparent'

        }else{
        //  Failed Test - Do Something
            input.style.background = '#FDD'

            all_valid = false
        }//endifelse

    }//endfor

    if(all_valid)
        return true;

    alert('That is not a valid entry')
    return false

}//endfunction
```

**HTML:**

```
<form onsubmit="return validateInputs(this);">
    <input type="text" pattern="(^[^0]$)" />
    <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

---

> To satisfy your question, a pattern of `(^[^0]$)` does *not* allow any
>   **blank** or **zero** value.

If you do not wish to validate an `<input>`, do not define the **pattern** attribute for it.